# Can I get "macro polymorphism" in C

Tags: c, macros

The type of polymorphism I'm after is this:

suppose I have a macro called draw(), and I have 2 structs, one called circle and the other called square. Is is possible to somehow do something like this:

```
#define draw() // can I get the text that's behind the macro?
//then maybe, with _Generic achieve this?


void draw_circle(struct circle);
void draw_square(struct square);

struct circle c;
struct square s;

c.draw();//draw is a macro. this time it is supposed to expand to draw_circle(c);
s.draw();//supposed to expand to draw_square(s);
```

**EDIT_1:** this is what I have so far, after reading your answers.

```
//raw_array.h
#pragma once
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define byte uint8_t
#define _GET_OVERRIDE(_1, _2, _3, NAME, ...) NAME
/*#define init_impl(...) _GET_OVERRIDE(__VA_ARGS__, \
    init_impl3, init_impl2, init_impl1)(__VA_ARGS__)
#define init( name, ... ) (raw_array * (name); init_impl( (name), __VA_ARGS__))*/

#define array_init_impl(...) _GET_OVERRIDE(__VA_ARGS__, init_array_impl3, init_array_impl2, init_array_impl1)(__VA_ARGS__)

///<summary>creates a variable of type raw_array with name as an identifier, and initializes based on the parameters</summary>
#define RAW_ARRAY( name, ... ) raw_array (name); array_init_impl( (&name), __VA_ARGS__)
typedef struct indexable_memory_block_struct
{
    raw_array * _self;
    byte * bytes;
    size_t element_size;
    size_t number_of_elements;

} raw_array;

///<summary>starts the an empty raw_array. only element_size is set.</summary>
///<param name=r_arr>the raw_array to be initialized</param>
///<param name=element_size>the size of the elements in this raw_array</param>
void init_impl1 ( raw_array * r_arr, size_t element_size )
{
    r_arr = malloc ( sizeof ( raw_array ) );
    r_arr->element_size = element_size;
    r_arr->number_of_elements = 0;
    r_arr->bytes = NULL;
    r_arr->_self = r_arr;
}

///<summary>
///starts the raw_array an empty. byte with its bytes allocated
///to their default value (0).
///</summary>
///<param name=r_arr>the raw_array to be initialized</param>
///<param name=element_size>the size of the elements in this raw_array</param>
///<param name=number_of_elements>the number of elements in the array</param>
void init_impl2 ( raw_array * r_arr, size_t element_size, size_t number_of_elements )
{
    r_arr = malloc ( sizeof ( raw_array ) );
    r_arr->element_size = element_size;
    r_arr->number_of_elements = number_of_elements;
    r_arr->bytes = calloc ( number_of_elements, element_size );
    r_arr->_self = r_arr;
}

///<summary>
///starts the raw_array copying its contents from a normal array.
///</summary>
///<param name=r_arr>the raw_array to be initialized</param>
///<param name=arr>the normal C array whose contents will be copied to this raw_array</param>
///<param name=element_size>the size of the elements in this    raw_array</param>
///<param name=number_of_elements>the number of elements in the array</param>
void init_impl3 ( raw_array * r_arr, const void * const arr, size_t size_of_element, size_t number_of_elements )
{
    r_arr->bytes = malloc ( size_of_element * number_of_elements );

    memcpy ( r_arr->bytes, arr, size_of_element * number_of_elements );
    r_arr->element_size = size_of_element;
    r_arr->number_of_elements = number_of_elements;
    r_arr->_self = r_arr;
}
```

there are other parts, but these are the ones currently being ported to this new syntax. Now main:

```
int main ( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    int data[30];

    //line bellow has a compilation error: *expected a ')'*
    init ( r_arr, data, sizeof ( int ), 30 );
}
```

what does it mean expected a ')'
could you guys check out the macro syntax?
About _Generic, I learned about it today, and I'll use it if it's useful, for sure.

**EDIT_2:** found a gross error, will be fixing it and editing again. Visual Studio is updating (12GB...) So I can't build anything at the moment. [mini-edit]: Guess I fixed the gross error at least. [mini-edit] another very bizarre error in my code, I stringifyed the name token, wth?! corrected now.

**EDIT_3:** having slept and having VS operational again, I fixed the macros, will edit them and comment out the wrong code. Now I need to the `circle.draw()` behaviour... any ideas?

Comment: Define `draw` to accept one `void *`. You'll need some way, perhaps a common first field in each `struct`ure, to know what exactly what you're operating on. A `switch` statement within `draw` can act accordingly.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use `draw(c)`? That would certainly work with `_Generic`. Or, alternatively, if you want C++ syntax, why don't you just use C++?

Comment: Post the error please.

Comment: the error was that I was using _self as the first argument to my init_impl1, 2, 3 calls, which was wrong, since that field is defined inside those methods. I can't compile or check for correctness of anything else, because VS is slowly updating and it cancels my *build* task the moment I start it.

Answer (score 8):

Besides @LirooPierre s approach, you could also use `C11` Generics. Yes you heard right, C has generics now.

Consider this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define draw(X) _Generic((X), \
        struct circle: draw_circle, \
        struct square: draw_square \
        )(X)

struct circle{};
struct square{};

void draw_circle(struct circle a)
{
    printf("Drawing a circle\n");
}
void draw_square(struct square a)
{
    printf("Drawing a square\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    struct square a;
    draw(a);  // "Drawing a square"
}
```

But even though it should be portable, it sadly is not. M$ Compiler doesn't implement them, but clang and gcc do.

Comment: This is a cool feature. Dunno why latest Microsoft compilers are not supporting it.. By the way if you try to implement this in Visual Studio, Intelli-Sense will give you `expected an expression` error.

Comment: @sjsam Most `C11` features are not supported up to this day, e.g. C11 threads. It's because probably nowadays `C` is not really a development language anymore, more of a maintaining language. Also M$ isn't really famous for keeping their software up-to-date (just look at the whole IE debacle, which haunts M$ up to this day, despite having a whole new browser)

Comment: ah...C is still widely used in the embedded world.

Answer (score 4):

You can really only achieve what want in c with function pointers

```
struct shape {
{
    void (*draw)(struct shape);
};

void draw_circle(struct shape);
void draw_square(struct shape);

#define CIRCLE(c) struct shape c; c.draw = &draw_circle;    
#define SQUARE(s) struct shape s; s.draw = &draw_square;
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
CIRCLE(c)
SQUARE(s)

c.draw(c);
s.draw(s);
```

You could add a draw macro too if you don't like the c.draw(c) syntax.

```
#define DRAW(shape) shape.draw(shape)

DRAW(c);
DRAW(s);
```

Comment: so Circle(c) is like a constructor of sorts. I think I like this.

Comment: That is pretty much what it is.

Comment: I would consider `c.draw(c)` to be too counter-intuitive and confusing to be useful.

Comment: I hear what you are saying, but think about it this way. C doesn't have a this pointer. This way of implementing it sort of fakes the this pointer or it makes so you can use the function as if it was a method of the object.

Comment: I would very much prefer c.draw(). I think I can achieve this. Only problem is VS2015 is unusable until it finishes updating. One day or another my whole C: drive will be filled with VisualStudio itself

Comment: You can't get `c.draw()` in pure C. In object oriented languages that understand this syntax, `c`,s type is used to find the appropriate method and a pointer to `c` is passed as a hidden parameter that you can use as `this` in the method. `c.draw()` is syntactic sugar for `draw_square(c)`. It is handled by the compiler and can't be replicated with C macros.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible !

You have to create a pointer on a function in your struct like this:

```
typedef void (*t_draw)(struct circle); //create a new type called t_draw
struct circle {
   t_draw draw;
}
```

Now in your code you have to assign a function in your struct:

```
struct circle c;

c.draw = &draw_circle;
```

and call it by using:

```
c.draw(/*your args*/);
```

Create the second structure square like the first and it should be OK !

Comment: the thing with this approach is I'll have to pass c as argument to c.draw(). I wanted a macro that would be able to expand that for me

Comment: Not sure but you could do : '#define draw(c) c.draw(c)' where c is your struct, then call it by using 'draw(c);'

Comment: No, that wouldn't do. if I could define (x).draw() and expand it to draw( (x) ), then it would do what I want